# Regular Expression extract 7 digit number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url like this and I want to extract and get the seven digit number after / and before .aspx, This is the sample url that I have. Is there any way I could extract the seven digit number after / and before .aspx?

This is what ive tried. but this only gets before?

```
  (?!\/)\d+(?=\?)
```

and this one

```
if(url.match(/\d{7}/)){  } // it returns true how can I get the value as well?
```

Sample url.

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/en-us/home/pages/technical/1234567.aspx?view=WebView
```

Thank you.

Comment: I've edited my post sorry.

Comment: if it's exactly 7 digits and only 7 digits and you only want to match 7 digits, I'd recommend `\d{7}`

Comment: yes Ive tried it like this     if(url.match(/\d{7}/)){, but this only returns true, how can also get the value?

Comment: Try `url.match(/\/(\d+)(?=\.)/)[0]`

Comment: indeed ... don't do `if` ...

Comment: If the number group is the only one in the url then do: `url.match(/\d+/)`. This returns the array: `[ "1234567" ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the pattern `.*/(\d+)`, and then access the first capture group:

```js
var url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/en-us/home/pages/technical/1234567.aspx?view=WebView";
var regex = /.*\/(\d+)/g;
var match = regex.exec(url);
console.log(match[1]); // 1234567
```

This works because the `.*` is greedy and will consume the entire url up until the last forward slash.  The numbers you wish to capture occur after that final forward slash.

Comment: `"www.shop18.com/21979/page/10/1234567.aspx?abc=yy763386"`

Comment: @Tushar I'm [not seeing a problem here](http://rextester.com/EQX18355).  Rather than dumping a cryptic URL under my answer, why don't you be more explicit?